# Oracle sql issue with dynamically created IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle

This makes a correct string in parenthesis and quoted.

```
select '('||REPLACE('''Binnenstad Boerhaavedistrict''',' ',''',''')||')' from dual
```

Namely:

> `('Binnenstad','Boerhaavedistrict')`

But when I use it in an `IN` statement it fails:

```
select dn.DISTRICTSNAAM 
from DISTRICTNAAM dn
where   dn.DISTRICTSNAAM in '('||REPLACE('''Binnenstad Boerhaavedistrict''',' ',''',''')||')'
```

No error, just no result.

My intent is to create the `IN` list from a space separated input variable.
But it only seems to work when I feed it a variable with quoted comma separated string.

Why is this? Or is it too dynamic?

Comment: You are creating a string or that is the final query?

Comment: An `IN` list contains a list of items.  You have created one with a single value, a long string.

Comment: use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and wrap everthing one more time in an outer set of quotes

Comment: It is a set-up with user multi-choice list. I use FME Translator to create a dynamic string. I wanted it in the sql query as that seems more elegant. Now i do the dynamic string creation in a scripted start parameter using TCL nested regsub and feed the sql the dynamicaly created string as a. this does the job.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `IN` compare to the full string instead of an array

```
where  dn.DISTRICTSNAAM in ( full string )
```

instead

```
where  dn.DISTRICTSNAAM in ( stringA, stringB)
```

Answer (score 0):

`in` will not parse a string containing comma-separated values. It will only handle a comma-separated list of strings.

`in ('a', 'b', 'c')` is okay.

`in ('''a''', ''b'', ''c''')` will only test a single value.

`in '(''a''', ''b'', ''c'')'` will also only test a single value.

To do what you're attempting, you will need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: i thought so...I did try execute immediate ttough, before i posted this question. Gave me some a invalid statement error. I will try again, tx anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **q-operator** for creating dynamic sql containing quotes. With this you can get rid of unnecessary quote marks.

For reference you can see 
http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=311
or https://community.oracle.com/thread/2146817